# Why the compiler doesn't error when using the async modifier on a method which doesn't await?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

The following code only raises an warning and compiles OK:

```
async void Do() {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Why does non-awaiting async methods are allowed? Makes no sense.

Please note I am not asking how async await works, I just want to know why the above code compiles without errors.

Comment: "allowed" is a strong term; it issues a warning (CS1998) - so... it isn't happy about it; also, you should effectively never use `async void`

Comment: counter-question: why _shouldn't_ they be allowed?

Comment: @MarcGravell I could see someone picking on that :P Let me rephrase :)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Because it produces useless state machinery code? Or it doesn't do that? I need to check. Either way, it could look like a strange warning, so why not have an error instead?

Comment: @DonBox "useless" is subjective; the "useless" state machinery still changes the exception behaviour (at least, when a task is returned) - if `Console.WriteLine` throws, a faulted task is *returned*; without the `async`, the method itself *throws*; this is nuanced but can matter

Comment: I see what you're saying, that's a good point Marc.

Comment: "The following code only raises an warning and compiles OK" - that sentence is an oxymoron; if it raised a warning, it did not "compile OK" - it compiled grudgingly and under duress; tip: always enable warnings-as-errors

Comment: Where do you stop? Should it also prevent compilation if it can prove that control flow cannot reach any `await` within the method? What if the control flow is beyond it's ability to prove things either way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *compiler* allows it because the compiler's job is to follow the language specification, and the language specification doesn't explicitly preclude this situation. Could it? Maybe. But there are *tons* of things that are obviously wrong yet which are semantically legal, and thus are allowed by the compiler. And in some of these cases, *including this one*, the compiler (or sometimes: an inbuilt analyzer, not strictly the compiler) issues a warning to call your attention to this fact. So: the compiler is more than aware that this isn't a great move, but the compiler also knows that it isn't meant to stop you *without a very good reason*.

Comment: Thanks, but then why does the "language specification" allows that? Isn't it clear you're adding await for no reason, so why do that? Or is it a pattern not to error unless it's really an error?

Comment: @DonBox the bug in this code is the use of `async void` which is only meant for asynchronous event handlers. In other cases - who says you didn't want to create a dummy async method for testing? `async` is just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await`. Once compiled, the method simply returns a `Task`

Comment: @DonBox assuming you mean "async" (not "await") - because no hard reason could be found to preclude it, ultimately

Answer (score 1):

Because introducing a new language feature that comes with too many restrictions, impedes the adoption of the new feature. The language designers quite reasonably believed in the power and usefullness of the new async-await functionality, and wanted to make its adoption as painless as possible. Permitting async-without-await would allow the developers to transition their applications from synchronous to asynchronous relatively easily. A developer would start by changing the **signature** of the methods from sync to async, keeping the **implementation** synchronous. Compiling the project would assure the developer that the signatures were right. Then they would just have to make async the implementations of the methods too, one method at a time, compiling the application along the way, until all the warnings had gone.

Imagine if it was obligatory to fix both the signatures and the implementations in one giant step, before being able to compile their application again...